# dc.js line chart starting from zero after each point

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have a line chart as shown in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/djmartin_umich/qBr7y/

The graph works fine and plots as expected. But I need one change to be made so that the plots become triangular shaped and I could see a series of irregular triangles. I mean after every point in Y, it should drop to 0 and start afresh. I know we could achieve this by explicitly adding data points to point to 0. But, just wondering if we could do that without creating additional data points.

HTML:

```
<div id="line-chart"></div>
<div id="log">Incoming Data:</div>
```

JS:

```
var startDate = new Date("2011-11-14T16:17:54Z");
var currDate = moment(startDate);
var cf = crossfilter([{date: startDate, quantity: 1}]);
AddData();

var timeDimension = cf.dimension(function(d){ return d.date; });
var totalGroup = timeDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d){ return d.quantity; });

var lineChart = dc.lineChart("#line-chart")
    .brushOn(false)
    .width(800)
    .height(200)
    .elasticY(true)
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]))
    .dimension(timeDimension)
    .group(totalGroup);

dc.renderAll();

window.setInterval(function(){
  AddData();
  lineChart.x(d3.time.scale().domain([startDate, currDate]));
  dc.renderAll();
}, 800);

function AddData(){
    var q = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    currDate = currDate.add('day', 5);
    cf.add( [{date: currDate.clone().toDate(), quantity: q}]);  
    $("#log").append(q + ", ");
}
```

CSS:

```
#log{
    clear:both;
}
```

Thanks,

Vicky

Comment: `I know we could achieve this by explicitly adding data points to point to 0` I would think thats the only way

Comment: You don't have to add it to your input data - you can preprocess the data the chart sees using a "fake group". I'll try to draw up an example. But if you could add a bit more detail why you want to do this, that will help. Does the data actually drop to zero and when?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to achieve this effect.

This is a general-purpose technique for preprocessing data that allows you to change what the chart sees without modifying the data in the crossfilter. In this case, we want to add a data point immediately after each point returned by the crossfilter group.

The fake group wraps the crossfilter group in an object that works like a group. Since in most cases dc.js only needs to call [group.all()](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_all), this is pretty easy:

```
function drop_to_zero_group(key_incrementor, group) {
    return {
        all: function() {
            var _all = group.all(), result = [];
            _all.forEach(function(kv) {
                result.push(kv);
                result.push({key: key_incrementor(kv.key), value: 0});
            })
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The fake group here produces two data points for each one it reads. The first is just a duplicate (or reference) of the original, and the second has its key incremented by a user-specified function.

It might make sense to parameterize this function by the zero value as well, but I mostly wanted to pull out the date incrementor, since that involves another trick. Here is a date incrementor:

```
function increment_date(date) {
    return new Date(date.getTime()+1);
}
```

This uses `date.getTime()` to get the integer value (in [milliseconds since the beginning of 1970](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)), adds one, and converts back to a date.

*Actually, the first time I tried this, I forgot to include `+1`, and it still worked! But I don't recommend that, since dc.js is likely to get confused if there is more than one point with the same x value.*

Apply the fake group by wrapping the group before passing it to the chart

```
lineChart
  .group(drop_to_zero_group(increment_date, totalGroup));
```

Here's a fork of DJ's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/dwfgma8j/4/

[image: line chart dropping to zero after each point]

FWIW I also changed `dc.renderAll()` to `dc.redrawAll()` in order to enable animated transitions instead of blinking white and rendering from scratch each time. The transitions are not perfect but I think it's still better than the blink. *I have a fix but it's a breaking change so it will go into dc.js 2.1.*

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'll try this out and keep you posted on the outcome!

Comment: Thanks a lot Gordon, works like a charm!!

Thanks,
Vicky

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped - not only does this provide me a few Fake Internet Points™ but it helps me track the long list of dc.js questions.